# Function calling variable output number

Tags: function, matlab, parameters, output

I've found myself trying to interface a custom class with builtin functions, and I've encoutered a situation I could only solve with eval, I'd like a "cleaner" way.

Basically, the builtin function is defined as `varargout=blabla(varargin)`
I defined an overriden function in the custom class, as `varargout=blabla(varargin)`. The function looks like:

```
function varargout=blabla(varargin)
    varargout=blabla(function_of_varargin)
end
```

The function of `varargin` transforms it from the custom class to the builtin clas.

But it doesn't work as-is: Basically when the builtin function is called inside the overriden function, it sees only one output parameter (`varargout`), even if the custom overriden function is called with more than one output parameter.

I solved it by basically calling this :

```
[varargout{1},varargout{2},...,varargout{nargout}]=blabla(function_of_varargin)
```

Constructing the LHS with a loop and eval-ing.

Comment: take a look at [How do I overload built-in MATLAB functions?](http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-18T0R/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-18T0R)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
[varargout{1:nargout}] = blabla(varargin{:})
```

?

Comment: Well, what do you know, when matlab knowledge runs dry, there's always some magic syntax to make it work. It works perfectly, Thanks

Comment: +1 good catch :) This is not limited to classes and member functions. Works for ordinary functions as well.

Comment: @angainor: Yup. Cell array expansion applied to the cell arrays `varargin` and `varargout` -- it's often overlooked. They really are just ordinary cell arrays :)